# Select (JavaScript, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una plantilla que me gustó pero es estática. Quiero agregarle funcionalidad pero tengo problemas.

Select:

```
<div class="select">
    <label class="label label-blur">Select option</label>
    <div class="select-label select-label-default">                                            
    <span class="Select-label-text" style="visibility: hidden">Select</span>                                         
    <span class="icon li_icon li_icon-arrow-down-small li_icon-small select-arrow-icon"></span>                                                                                                                    
</div>                                                                                                                    
<ul class="select-menu select-menu-hide">                                                         
    <div><li id="0" aria-selected="true" class="select-menu-options select-menu-options-focused" role="option">Select</li></div>
    <div><li id="1" aria-selected="false" class="select-menu-options" role="option">Option 1</li></div>
    <div><li id="2" aria-selected="false" class="select-menu-options" role="option">Option 2</li></div>
    <div><li id="3" aria-selected="false" class="select-menu-options" role="option">Option 3</li></div>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".select").click(() => {
    $(".select-menu").removeClass("select-menu-hide").addClass("select-menu-show");
});

$(".select-menu div li").click(() => {
    // $(this).attr("aria-selected", false);
    $(this).not($(this)).attr("aria-selected", true);
    // let v = $("li[aria-selected='true']").text();
    // console.log(v);
});
```

¿Cómo puedo activar una opción, obtener su texto y pasarlo al label?

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo que podrás tomar como base aunque no se adapta directamente al código que has incluido en tu pregunta. Pero creo que te dará una idea de qué puedes hacer para empezar (tomado de [aquí](https://masqueweb.es/menu-desplegable-html-css-jquery/) porque era más rápido que limpiar el código que tengo en mis proyectos).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Menu Toggle</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    //Botón de acción del acordeón
    $('.dropdownButton').click(function() {

        //Elimina la clase on de todos los botones
        $('.dropdownButton').removeClass('on');

        //Plegamos todo el contenido que esta abierto
        $('.dropdownContent').slideUp('slow');

        //Si el siguiente slide no esta abierto lo abrimos
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

            //Añade la clase on en el botón
            $(this).addClass('on');

            //Abre el slide
            $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
         }

     });

    // Cerramos todo el contenido al cargar la página
    $('.dropdownContent').hide();

});
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
  body{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
}
.dropdownMenu{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.title{
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background-color: #994b4b;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.title:hover{
    background-color: #c26060;
}
.dropdownButton:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdownButton > p .fa{
    float: right;
}
.dropdownContent ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.dropdownContent,
.dropdownButton{
    border: 1px solid #994b4b;
}
.dropdownContent{
    padding: 15px 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.dropdownContent ul li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.dropdownContent ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdownContent ul li a:hover{
    color: blue;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="dropdownMenu">
        <div class="title dropdownButton">
            <p>MENU I</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdownContent">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM I</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM II</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdownMenu">
        <div class="title dropdownButton">
            <p>MENU II</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdownContent">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM I</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM II</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

También lo puedes hacer en forma de barras de navegación con [boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) y quedan muy bien. [Aquí](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/bootstrap-3/capitulo-6/barras-de-navegacion) hay un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo.